# How to merge with Observable inside loop in javascript?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In angular project i have list of processes, i need to get linked processes of each process and merge them into one single array. The thing is the only way to get list of linked processes is through the use of observable method. What rxjs methods i should use and how to get that linked list of processes? i am new to rxjs.

I have tried just to push each result to the final array but get an error like 
`cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

````
let processToProcessLinkList = [];
listOfProcesses.forEach(process => {
    // populate link list
    this.processEndpoint.processLinkedProcessList(process.id, new DataSourceRequest()).subscribe(result => {
        if(result.success) {
            result.data.forEach(element => {
                this.processToProcessLinkList.push(element);    
            }); 
        // this.processToProcessLinkList.push(...result.data);                      
    } 
}
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you start with an array `listOfProcesses`. For each element in the array you have to make a call to the endpoint via `this.processEndpoint.processLinkedProcessList`. Eventually you have to collect all the responses into the array `processToProcessLinkList`.

If this is the case, you could try something along these lines

```
// create an array of Observables representing the requests to the end point, one per element in the array listOfProcesses
const requests = listOfProcesses.map(p => this.processEndpoint.processLinkedProcessList(p.id, new DataSourceRequest()));

// execute all requests in parallel to get an array of responses
forkJoin(requests)
.subscribe(responses => processToProcessLinkList = responses)
```

Note 1: the error `cannot read property 'push' of undefined` seems to be linked to the fact that `processToProcessLinkList` is defined as a local variable and not as a property of a class.

Note 2: I suggest to read something about Observables and http requests such as [this article](https://medium.com/@enrico.piccinin/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)